# Objective-c clear cache NSCachedURLResponse

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching

I ran this code because I think I am running into a caching issue:

```
NSCachedURLResponse *response = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request];
    if(response){
        NSLog(@"Got Response");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"No Response");
    }
```

my question is how do I clear cache for the request URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLRequest has a cachePolicy property, which specifies the caching behaviour of the request.

Set the following cache policy **NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData** when making the request like the example bellow will load the data from the url and not from the cache.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
```

> NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
>
> Specifies that the data for the URL load should be loaded from the
>   originating source. No existing cache data should be used to satisfy a
>   URL load request.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSURLRequestCachePolicy

Answer (score 0):

Use removeCachedResponseForRequest: method of NSURLCache class.

[Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcache#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001699-SW5)